# SQL Server not finding the string with brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one record in table `Payment(id int, message nvarchar(500))`, I have inserted row with id=1 and message="Wrong param [abonentCode]:".

When I try to select the record with message "Wrong param [abonentCode]:" sql server returns 0 rows.

I have tried these statements and none of them works:

```
SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE message = N'Wrong param [abonentCode]:'
SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE message = 'Wrong param [abonentCode]:'
```

Comment: what do you get when you exclude the where clause?

Comment: Just tested this in SQL Server 2014 and it works fine.  Unable to replicate the problem.

Comment: Any idea? Can I check if row has some special characters like ENTER or something like that?

Comment: According to [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/399e0/1) this works fine in both 2008 and 2014.

Comment: @DavitLekishvili You can. Just cast the string from the row with id 1 you've inserted to varbinary and check ascii codes of symbols. Also cast string you're trying to find to varbinary and check codes.

Comment: try SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE message Like 'Wrong param%'

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I got this string - 0x57726F6E6720706172616D205B61626F6E656E74436F64655D3A20636F6D What can I guess?

Comment: Also try this: select * from the table with no where clause. highlight the cell with your data, and paste into an advanced text editor like Notepad2, or visual studio text editor and show whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look to binary data obtained from inserted string you've provided in comments:

```
0x57726F6E6720706172616D205B61626F6E656E74436F64655D3A20636F6D
```

Casting it back to varchar gives us:

```
Wrong param [abonentCode]: com
```

But you're trying to find it as

```
WHERE message = 'Wrong param [abonentCode]:'
```

Notice strings mismatch (extra `com` at the end of inserted string) - so you can't use equality operator here.

Possible options:

1. Correct string you're using in where condition in order to find by strong equality;
2. Use substring:

```
select *  from Payment where left(message, 26) = 'Wrong param [abonentCode]:'
```

3. Use `like` operator (notice in this case you have to add `%` to the pattern to denote any number of any characters as well as put opening square bracket into enclosing brackets to escape it since pair of square brackets has special meaning in like operator patterns):

```
select *  from Payment where message like 'Wrong param [[]abonentCode]:%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the opening bracket (surround it with []).

I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE message LIKE 'Wrong param [[]abonentCode]:%'
```

(Also note the possible need of a trailing %)

Sorry, above should be LIKE, not =

Comment: Frankly speaking, this escaping is needed only in the case of `like` operator since pair of square brakets has a special meaning only in this operator pattern and not generally in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when executed in SQL 2008 Or 2014.

[See SQL Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60976/1/0)